# Revert CHMOD 666 cmd for Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, chmod

I've installed Docker on an Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I received permissions error when trying to run docker commands, so I run this command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now I found that the tidy solution is to follow next steeps:

- Create the docker group.

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

- Add your user to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

- You would need to loog out and log back in so that your group    membership is re-evaluated or type the following command:

```
su -s ${USER}
```

As I'm new with Linux management, I'm not sure on how to revert the last chmod command.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If receives "ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"  1- sudo service docker start 2- sudo chmod 0660 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock` is generally owned by user `root` and group `docker`, with mode 0660 (read/write permissions for owner and group, no permissions for others).

```
sudo chmod 0660 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Remember that anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can trivially root the host

```
docker run --rm -it -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers
```

For a development system adding your normal user to the `docker` group might be acceptable; if you have actual production-oriented data on the system, requiring `sudo` might be more appropriate.